# Filter For openVidu

Tags: angular, filter, video-streaming, streaming, openvidu

I'm using the openVidu in my project, for making calls

for that I'm using filter which is GStreamerFilter (textoverlay)

I have a good related to it in two different locations
first part:

```
const filter: any = {
            type: "GStreamerFilter",
            options: {
                command: 'textoverlay text="' + LabelUserName 
                + '            " valignment=top halignment=center font-desc="Arial, 12"'
            }
        };
         
        const properties = this.openViduWebRTCService.createPublisherProperties(videoSource
            , audioSource
            , true
            , hasAudio
            , false
            , filter);
```

the second part of code:

```
publisher.stream.applyFilter(
                    "GStreamerFilter", 
                    {'command': 'textoverlay text="' + LabelUserName
                    + '            " valignment=top halignment=center font-desc="Arial, 12"'}
                );
```

My question(s):

- Can I use another filter in the GStreamerFilter at the same time with textoverlay , for example applying clockoverlay and textoverlay together at the same time ?!
  and if yes how to do that?!
- Can I apply a virtual background with the  GStreamerFilter at the same time?

Please note that I'm using openVidu Pro.